# How to design database to handle which users have watched which videos?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-normalization

For the sake of simplicity, let's say my database has two tables, videos and users. 
Videos being a list of different videos, and users being a list of different users.

I need to be able to have a record of when a user watches a certain video, so when they go to view the video again, I can let them know that they have already seen it.

Info: 
There will potentially be hundreds of thousands of users
There will potentially be hundreds of thousands of videos.

One way I have thought of doing this is buy creating a table for each video, or a table for each user (Both would result in hundreds of thousands of tables).

Another way would be to create one neutral table, with the fields: userID(foreign key), videoID(foreign key).  However, I believe this compromises efficiency (and normalization) because there would be multi-valued dependencies, or multiples of the same userID's and videoID's in the two columns.

I am still fairly new to databases, and I feel like I am missing something simple.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your database should have a table for `users`, a table for `videos` and a table for `userViews`. `userViews` contains fields `userId` and `videoId` and a time/date field. Fill it up as people watch videos.

Normalization is not compromised.

Comment: You can have a composite primary key (UserID and VideoId), and those can also both be foreign keys. This is exactly your second idea. DO NOT create one table per video to keep track of this

Answer (score 1):

Your "*Another way*" idea is on the right track. It's called a [junction or join table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) and is frequently used when you need a many to many relationship. In addtion to `UserId` and `VideoId` you would add a `WatchedDateTime` column to track when the viewing took place.

Wikipedia image example:

[image]

Do not make a composite key of UserId and VideoId since that won't let you record multiple watchings.

Answer (score 0):

Having a dependency/relationship/link/join/junction table like you mentioned in option2 will be perfect. To be doubly sure you may want to make that composite key (UserId, VideoId) a Primary/Unique constraint so that duplication could be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to research many-to-many relationships in T-SQL: http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Understanding_SQL_Many_to_Many_Relationships.aspx

Once you're familiar with this, make sure you've got narrow identity columns in the User and Video tables (INT will work), then create a third table called UserVideos that will reference both tables via foreign keys.  If you give the third table a timestamp, it will show when the user watched the video.